# Generating never used before random number in SQL

Tags: sql, random, unique

I am using the function below to generate a random number between 0 and 99999999999.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rndView]
AS
SELECT RAND() rndResult
GO



ALTER function [dbo].[RandomPass]()
RETURNS NUMERIC(18,0)
 as
    begin
    DECLARE @RETURN NUMERIC(18,0)
    DECLARE @Upper NUMERIC(18,0);
    DECLARE @Lower NUMERIC(18,0);
    DECLARE @Random float;

    SELECT @Random = rndResult
    FROM rndView

      SET @Lower = 0 
      SET @Upper = 99999999999 
      set @RETURN= (ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * @Random + @Lower), 0))

 return @RETURN
 end;
```

However, I need to make sure that the returned number has never been used before in the same app. In .net I would create a while loop and keep looping until the returned value is not found in a table that stores previously used values. Is there a way to achieve the same result directly in SQL, ideally without using loops? If there is no way to do that without loops, I think it would still be more efficient to do it in an SQL function rather than having a loop in .net performing a number of query requests.

Comment: `function`s in SQL can't change the database state, so may be a non-starter for this, since you need some kind of mutation to track history.

Comment: Why not just use a Sequence? What benefit is the "randomness" adding?

Comment: @NickW it's a client requirement

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the used values in a table, and a recursive query to generate the next value.

The answer depends on the RDBMS you are using.

Below are two examples, in PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server, that would solve your problem.

## PostgreSQL

First, create a table that will hold your consumed ids :

```
CREATE TABLE consumed_ids (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` is not strictly necessary, but it will

1. generate an index which will speed up the next query;
2. ensure that two equal ids are never generated.

Then, use the following query to obtain a new id :

```
WITH RECURSIVE T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS n, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 100000000000) AS v
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 100000000000)
  FROM T
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM consumed_ids WHERE id = v)
)
INSERT INTO consumed_ids
SELECT v
FROM T
ORDER BY n DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURNING id;
```

The logic is that as long as the (last) id generated is already consumed, we generate a new id. The column `n` of the CTE is there only to retrieve the last generated id at the end, but you may also use it to limit the number of generated random numbers (for example, give up if `n > 10`).

(tested using PostgreSQL 12.4)

## MS SQL Server

First, create a table that will hold your consumed ids :

```
CREATE TABLE consumed_ids (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Then, use the following query to obtain a new id :

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS n, FLOOR(RAND() * 100000000000) AS v
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1, FLOOR(RAND() * 100000000000)
  FROM T
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM consumed_ids WHERE id = v)
)
INSERT INTO consumed_ids (id)
OUTPUT Inserted.id
SELECT TOP 1 v
FROM T
ORDER BY n DESC;
```

(tested using MS SQL Server 2019).

Note however that MS SQL Server will give up after 100 tries by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a random number without replacement.

You need to store the numbers that have already been used in a table, which I would define as:

```
create table used_random_numbers (
    number decimal(11, 0) primary key
);
```

Then, when you create a new number, insert it into the table.

In the part of the code that generates a number, use a `while` loop.  Within the `while` loop, check that the number doesn't exist.

Now, there are some things you can do to make this more efficient as the numbers grow larger  -- and ways that don't require remembering all the previous values.

First, perhaps UUID/GUID is sufficient.  This is the industry standard for a "random" id -- although it is a HEX string rather than a number in most databases.  The exact syntax depends on the database.

Another approach is to have an 11 digit number.  The first or last 10 digits could be the Unix epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01) -- either explicitly or under some transformation so the value "looks" random.  The additional digit would then be a random digit.  Of course, you could extend this to minutes or days so you have more random digits.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That is mostly how I am doing it. I do have a table that stores previously used numbers (3 actually which are combined using UNION) and every number I generate is checked against this table to see if it has been used before. I was hoping there was a way to do it without looping and making multiple queries. Like, sort of (pseudo code), SELECT RandomNumber WHERE RandomNumber NOT IN (SELECT......)

Comment: @Osprey . . . I explained some alternative methods.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, unfortunately I cannot use a Unique ID because I am restricted to 11 numeric characters and I cannot use the time because sometimes the possible results are restricted to numbers starting with a specific two digit prefix. This might vary from user to user and some users don't have it at all.